# Base Constructor Not Executing

Tags: c#

I have a private type that should be instantiated in the constructor. I have base constructor and another with parameters. I kept instantiation in the base and only the variable assignment in parameterized constructor. But it is not working.

This is not working.

```
public class MainClass
{
    private MyType myType = null;
    private string myParm = string.Empty;

    private MainClass()
    {
        myType = new MyType();
    }

    public MainClass(string inParm) : base()
    {
        myParm = inParm;
    }
}
```

The below is working,

```
public class MainClass
{
    private MyType myType = null;
    private string myParm = string.Empty;

    private MainClass()
    {
    }

    public MainClass(string inParm): base()
    {
        myType = new MyType();
        myParm = inParm;
    }
}
```

myType is not initialized when kept in base constructor

Comment: `base()` is for calling the constructor of a parent class, which is `object` for this class. `object` doesn't know anything about `myType`. You're probably looking for `this()` instead.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks for explaining it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you want `this()` not `base()`.  You want to call the constructor on the same class, not its base class:

```
public MainClass(string inParm) : this()
{
   myParm = inParm;
}
```

By default, a class will call its base class's default constructor, as it's a requirement to construct itself.  If there is no default constructor on the base class, you'd have to supply the correct parameters to satisfy the construction of the base class.

But your base class is `Object`, so no need to worry about it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to call `this()` not `base()` because you are not calling the parent constructor:

```
public class MainClass
{
    private MyType myType = null;
    private string myParm = string.Empty;

    private MainClass()
    {
        myType = new MyType();
    }

    public MainClass(string inParm)
        : this()
    {
        myParm = inParm;
    }
}
```